# Removing parentheses from JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

I´m trying to send as a POST request to a server the following JSON:

```
{
    "in_app" =     (
                {
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-06-04 **:41:51 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 14019****00;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-06-04 11:41:51 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000******9249;
            "product_id" = "com.mysite.myinfo.myinapp";
            "purchase_date" = "2014-06-06 13:25:59 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 140******9000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-06-06 06:25:59 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1******13019249;
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see, this JSON has () on it.
But the server will only accept something like this:

```
{
    "in_app" =  {
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2014-06-04 **:41:51 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 14019****00;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2014-06-04 11:41:51 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000******9249;
            "product_id" = "com.mysite.myinfo.myinapp";
            "purchase_date" = "2014-06-06 13:25:59 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 140******9000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2014-06-06 06:25:59 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1******13019249;
   }
}
```

How can I get rid go the parenthesis on iOS?

I get the JSON using:

```
NSDictionary *receiptDict = [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"receipt"]objectForKey:@"in_app"];
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to remove the parenthesis your json is returning an array, parenthesis in response represents array(can be added in NSArray or NSMutableArray)

Just use it like this

```
NSMutableArray *arrInApp = [yourDictionaryObject objectForKey:@"in_app"];
```

then you can do

```
NSDictionary *indexDict = [arrInApp objectAtIndex:0];
```

your indexDict will have all the values as a dictionary.